# React Native Background Geolocation stationary not working

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I'm using https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation and stationary is not working. My provider is **DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER**, I followed the code

```
BackgroundGeolocation.on('stationary', (stationaryLocation) => {
  // handle stationary locations here
  console.log(stationaryLocation, 'STATIONARY')
});
```

but nothing is showing in the console.log, removing the **BackgroundGeolocation.on('location', (location) => {})** and it shows the stationary. How is that happened? can someone helped me on how to used stationary. I'm using it in auto pause. I appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code.

add this to your configuration object

```
stationaryRadius: 50
```

When you are using console.log and you need to add a string variable, you need to concatenate with + sign

```
BackgroundGeolocation.on('stationary', (stationaryLocation) => {
      // handle stationary locations here
      console.log(stationaryLocation + "STATIONARY")
    });
```

or try logging with

Comment: `desiredAccuracy: BackgroundGeolocation.HIGH_ACCURACY,
  locationProvider: BackgroundGeolocation.DISTANCE_FILTER_PROVIDER,
  stationaryRadius: 50,
  distanceFilter: 50,
  notificationTitle: 'Sample',
  notificationText: 'Tract your run!',
  startOnBoot: true,
  stopOnTerminate: true,`

Here's my config but still stationary is not showing